# PySpark groupByKey returning pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to figure out why my groupByKey is returning the following:

```
[(0, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a210>), (1, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a4d0>), (2, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a390>), (3, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a290>), (4, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a450>), (5, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a350>), (6, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a1d0>), (7, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a490>), (8, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a050>), (9, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7fc659e0a650>)]
```

I have flatMapped values that look like this:

```
[(0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (0, u'D')]
```

I'm doing just a simple:

```
groupRDD = columnRDD.groupByKey()
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

What you're getting back is an object which allows you to iterate over the results. You can turn the results of groupByKey into a list by calling list() on the values, e.g.

```
example = sc.parallelize([(0, u'D'), (0, u'D'), (1, u'E'), (2, u'F')])

example.groupByKey().collect()
# Gives [(0, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object ......]

example.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()
# Gives [(0, [u'D', u'D']), (1, [u'E']), (2, [u'F'])]
```

Comment: `example.groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()` is shorter and also works

Comment: How can I map through the `ResultIterable` type?

Answer (score 31):

you can also use

```
example.groupByKey().mapValues(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using groupByKey(), i would suggest you use cogroup(). You can refer the below example.

```
[(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(x.cogroup(y).collect()))]
```

Example:

```
>>> x = sc.parallelize([("foo", 1), ("bar", 4)])
>>> y = sc.parallelize([("foo", -1)])
>>> z = [(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(x.cogroup(y).collect()))]
>>> print(z)
```

You should get the desired output...

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
r1 = sc.parallelize([('a',1),('b',2)])
r2 = sc.parallelize([('b',1),('d',2)])
r1.cogroup(r2).mapValues(lambda x:tuple(reduce(add,__builtin__.map(list,x))))
```

Result:

```
[('d', (2,)), ('b', (2, 1)), ('a', (1,))]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers, if you want the sorted list of unique items, use following:

**List of Distinct and Sorted Values**

```
example.groupByKey().mapValues(set).mapValues(sorted)
```

**Just List of Sorted Values**

```
example.groupByKey().mapValues(sorted)
```

**Alternative's to above**

```
# List of distinct sorted items
example.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], sorted(set(x[1]))))

# just sorted list of items
example.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], sorted(x[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your code is..

```
ex2 = ex1.groupByKey()
```

And then you run..

```
ex2.take(5)
```

You're going to see an iterable.  This is okay if you're going to do something with this data, you can just move on.  But, if all you want is to print/see the values first before moving on, here is a bit of a hack..

```
ex2.toDF().show(20, False)
```

or just

```
ex2.toDF().show()
```

This will show the values of the data.  You shouldn't use `collect()` because that will return data to the driver, and if you're working off a lot of data, that's going to blow up on you.  Now if `ex2 = ex1.groupByKey()` was your final step, and you want those results returned, then yes use `collect()` but make sure that you know your data being returned is low volume.

```
print(ex2.collect())
```

Here is another nice post on using collect() on RDD

[View RDD contents in Python Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295277/view-rdd-contents-in-python-spark)