# PySpark groupByKey finding tuple length

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My questions is based upon the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717257/pyspark-groupbykey-returning-pyspark-resultiterable-resultiterable). I want to count elements for the key, how could i do that?

```
example = sc.parallelize([(alpha, u'D'), (alpha, u'D'), (beta, u'E'), (gamma, u'F')])


abc=example.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()
# Gives [(alpha, [u'D', u'D']), (beta, [u'E']), (gamma, [u'F'])]
```

I want output something like below

```
alpha:2,beta:1, gamma:1
```

I came to know that the answer is below. Why is it so complex? is there a simpler answer? does s contain key + all values? Why cannot I do len(s)-1 where I am subtracting one to remove the key s[0]

```
map(lambda s: (s[0], len(list(set(s[1])))))
```

Comment: It's not complex. The way how we do this is because it's based in `map-reduce` paradigm, which is based in transformations and reductions.

Comment: I can't be `alpha:2,beta:1, gamma:2`, it shall be `alpha:2,beta:1, gamma:1`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not complex. What you really need here is yet another word count:

```
from operator import add

example.map(lambda x: (x[0], 1)).reduceByKey(add)
```

If you plan to `collect` you can even `countByKey`:

```
example.countByKey()
```

You really don't want to use `groupByKey` here but assuming there is some hidden reason to apply it after all:

```
example.groupByKey().mapValues(len)
```

Why `len(s) - 1` doesn't work? Simply because `example` is a pairwise RDD or in other words it contains key-value pairs. Same thing applies to the result of `groupByKey`. It means that `len(s)` is always equal 2.

Comment: appreciate your answer. But would it be possible to explain why `map(lambda s: (s[0], len(list(set(s[1])))))` works? Does s contain key + all values? Why cannot I do len(s)-1 where I am subtracting one to remove the key s[0]

Comment: your update helps. But isn't my `abc` rdd consist of a tuple (key:value1, value2 value3 etc)? Printing abc gives me `Gives [(alpha, [u'D', u'D']), (beta, [u'E']), (gamma, [u'F'])]`.

Comment: No. It is (key, values)