# Iterating through a Spark RDD

Tags: python, vector, apache-spark, pyspark

Starting with a Spark DataFrame to create a vector matrix for further analytics processing.

```
feature_matrix_vectors = feature_matrix1.map(lambda x: Vectors.dense(x)).cache()
feature_matrix_vectors.first()
```

The output is an array of vectors. Some of those vector have an null in them

```
>>> DenseVector([1.0, 31.0, 5.0, 1935.0, 24.0])
...
>>> DenseVector([1.0, 1231.0, 15.0, 2008.0, null])
```

From this i want to iterate through the vector matrix and create an LabeledPoint array with 0 (zero) if the vector contains a null, otherwise with a 1.

```
def f(row):
    if row.contain(None):
       LabeledPoint(1.0,row)
    else:
       LabeledPoint(0.0,row)
```

I have tried to iterate through the vector matrix using

```
feature_matrix_labeledPoint = (f(row) for row in feature_matrix_vectors) #   create a generator of row sums
next(feature_matrix_labeledPoint) # Run the iteration protocol
```

but this doesn't work.

```
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable
```

Any help would be great

Comment: This SO answer has the details http://stackoverflow.com/a/25296061/429476

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RDDs` are not a drop in replacement for a Python lists. You have to use either actions or transformations which are available on a given `RDD`. Here you can simply use `map`:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint


feature_matrix_vectors = sc.parallelize([
    DenseVector([1.0, 31.0, 5.0, 1935.0, 24.0]),
    DenseVector([1.0, 1231.0, 15.0, 2008.0, None])
])

(feature_matrix_vectors
    .map(lambda v: LabeledPoint(1.0 if None in v else 0.0, v))
    .collect())
```