# Non-Empty Spark Dataset foreach not executing

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to read a Cassandra table (`mykeyspace.mytable`) from inside a Spark 2.1 job (using Scala 2.11):

```
val myDataset = sqlContext
     .read
     .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
     .options(Map("table" -> "mytable", "keyspace" -> "mykeyspace"))
     .load()

myDataset.show()

println(s"Ping and the count is: ${myDataset.count}")
myDataset.foreach(t => println("Weee"))
println("Pong")
```

When this runs, the console output is:

```
+--------------+-----------+
|      username|modified_at|
+--------------+-----------+
|sluggoo-flibby|       null|
+--------------+-----------+

Ping and the count is: 1
Pong
```

So there's *clearl* a single record in this table...**but why is my `foreach` loop "not working?"** Why don't I see my "Weee" output?

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelRoth it was a twenry carrot without most console implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't see the output because `println` outputs to the standard output of the worker, not driver. This is a common mistake with RDDs ([View RDD contents in Python Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25295277/8371915)), but it applies also to `Dataset`.

You can `collect` but it of course is not advised for large data:

```
 myDataset.collect.foreach(t => println("Weee"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreach operation doesn't run on your local machine.. it runs on the remote machine where your spark executors are running. Thus the println is not executed on your local machine but on the remote executor.

to have it printed on your local machine you should collect on the dataframe and have all the data of the dataframe on your driver (which runs on your local machine) and execute a foreach on that local collection as shown below.

```
myDataset.collect.foreach(println)
```

**Note**: be careful on using `collect` on a `RDD` or a `Dataframe`. collect downloads all the data from the distributed collection to the local memory which could lead to `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` Exceptions.