# The function in map is not executed

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, pyspark

I want to execute the "execute" function inside the map to csvLine but it is not executed

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", 
auth=basic_auth("neo4j","azerty"), encrypted=False)
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys

def execute(line):
    print('Hola')
    session = driver.session()
    session.run("CREATE (n:Node {value: {v} })", {'v': int(line[0])})
    session.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext()
    csvData = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1]).cache()
    print("VOila")    
    csvData.map(execute)    
"""
    session = driver.session()    
    session.run("CREATE (n:Node {value: {v1} })-[:FRIEND]->(m:Node {value: {v2}})",{'v1': 1, 'v2':2})    
    print('fini')
    session.close()
"""
```

I call the execute function but is not executed

Comment: Additionally [View RDD contents in Python Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25295277/8371915)